# Microsoft Graph API - Batch - licensedetails returns no value

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to get License Details for a user from the Microsoft Graph API endpoint /users/{id}/licenseDetails it works fine as a single api call, but if i try to do a batch request then it returns no data in the value.
Trying to get the details for a subscription assigned to a user, that shows all the individual apps under a license and their status, this endpoint seems to be the only way. the licensedetails is not supported as a $expand under /users and none of the other properties returned under /users gives those details. Since this seems to be the only endpoint to give this info, and it requires it be called for every user to get the details, it is a lot of API calls to get the info for every user of a tenant. I am trying to use batching to combine 20 calls at a time but even though it returns status code 200 and shows that it used the proper id's for each user and the proper endpoint which I can see from the @odata.context that is returned.
I am using powershell for this and putting making the call as a Invoke-RestMethod.

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $data.count;$i+=20){                                                                                                                                              
    $req = @{}                                                     
    $req['requests'] = ($data[$i..($i+19)] 
        | select @{n='id';e={$_.id}},@{n='method';e={'GET'}},`
        @{n='url';e={"/users/$($_.id)/licenseDetails"}})
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST `
        -URI "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`$batch" `
        -body ($req | convertto-json) `
                -Headers $HeaderParams
    foreach ($bat in $response.responses) {                                    
        if($bat.status -eq 200){
        write-host "$($bat.body)"
        } else {
            write-host "failed"
        }                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                              
}
```

What is returned in the $response.responses.body are:
@{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('99ce89e8-7803-42a2-a387-fbc0bb60db70')/licenseDetails; value=System.Object[]}

and all of the returned $response.responses.body.value are null

If I run the same user ID directly to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($_.id)/licenseDetails and not to /batch, it returns all the licensedetials for the user.
Has anyone been able to get licensedetails to work with batching? Or anyway to be able to get those details for all users in the tenant without having to make an API call per user? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the batch calls up to 20 with the script below.

```
$ACCESS_TOKEN_SAMLE = "eyJ0..."

# Define your header with the access token
$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN_SAMLE"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}


$req1 = @{
    id     = "d79c2cdc..."
    method = 'GET'
    url    = "/users/d79c2cdc.../licenseDetails"
}

$req2 = @{
    id     = "1a913aed..."
    method = 'GET'
    url    = "/users/1a913aed.../licenseDetails"
}
$my_requests =  @($req1, $req2)
$other_req = $(1..18) | % {
        @{
            id     = $_
            method = 'GET'
            url    = "/users/$($_)/licenseDetails"
        }
    }
    
$req = @{
    requests = $($my_requests; $other_req)
}

$body = $req | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -URI 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch' -Body $body -Headers $Headers

foreach ($bat in $response.responses) {
    if ($bat.status -eq 200) {
        $body = $bat.body 
        $licenses = $body.value
        write-host "$($bat.id): $($licenses.count) licenses"
    }
    else {
        write-host "failed"
    }
}
```

Outout ------

```
PS C:\Users\name\Code\random_scripts> .\graph-api-batch.ps1
failed
1a913aed-...: 1 licenses
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
failed
d79c2cdc-...: 1 licenses
failed
failed
PS C:\Users\name\Code\random_scripts>
```